# Output Redirection produces empty file ONLY with jq

Tags: windows, batch-file, jq, overwrite, io-redirection

I'm having an interesting issue. I'm using jq to minify JSON from a batch script, and I want it to replace the file it reads from. While there is probably a better solution, this, while it *should* work on paper, it does ***not*** work in practice.

#### Works:

```
for /R %%f in (*.json) do (
    ECHO Minifying JSON file "%%f"
    (ECHO Hello) 1> "%%f"
)
```

**Output Files:**

```
Hello
```

---

#### Shows that the redirect works

```
for /R %%f in (*.json) do (
    ECHO Minifying JSON file "%%f"
    ("path\to\jq" . --unbuffered --compact-output "%%f" && ECHO Hello) 1> "%%f"
)
```

**Output Files:**

```
Hello
```

---

#### Shows that jq produces output

```
for /R %%f in (*.json) do (
    ECHO Minifying JSON file "%%f"
    "path\to\jq" . --unbuffered --compact-output "%%f"
)
```

**Output in CMD Window:** Contents of each JSON file, minified (just like I want it)

---

#### What I'm *trying* to do

```
for /R %%f in (*.json) do (
    ECHO Minifying JSON file "%%f"
    ("path\to\jq" . --unbuffered --compact-output "%%f") 1> "%%f"
)
```

**Output Files:**

As you can see, there is no JSON present, minified or otherwise.

---

## On the answer

[@peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) gave [a workaround using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68135948/13076790). In my situation, I came out with the following:

```
for /R %%f in (*.json) do (
    ECHO Minifying JSON file "%%f"
    powershell -Command "& {.\..\info\jq . --unbuffered --compact-output \"%%f\"|Set-Content \"%%f\"}"
)
```

This outputs the correct, minified JSON.
What I'm doing here is invoking PowerShell to handle the minification, and using the Set-Content cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it works or seem to work, blindly overwriting an input file using output redirection is usually a bad idea, or worse.

In an environment in which the (well-known)
[sponge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207919/sponge-from-moreutils-whats-the-difference-to-shell-redirect-useful-examples)  utility is available, it can be used, but it looks like you might not have that luxury, so you might want to consider a more mundane approach using a temporary file.

PowerShell users can use SetContent:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 2):

You can't overwrite the file you are reading from, because the first action will be the (re)creation of the file by the redirection, then `jq` will read from an empty file.

Just redirect to a temporary file and replace the original file after finishing.

Answer (score 1):

The `jq` repo has a FAQ about this, [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ), under

> : How can "in-place" editing of a JSON file be accomplished?

This says

> ...using tee or output redirection (>) to overwrite the input file is not recommended, even if it seems to work.

One easy fix suggested there is using `sponge` from [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/). On macOS, one could do

```
$ brew install jq sponge
```

`apt` and `npm` can be used similarly.

With `sponge`, an in-place format of a json file would be

```
$ jq . my.json | sponge my.json
```

Comment: The sponge approach still produces an empty file

Comment: Strange, and sorry it didn't work for you. 

This _is_ a suggested approach in the jq repo, and it works like a charm for me (using brew on macOS 12.6).